# Error while using FROM_UNIXTIME(UNIX_TIMESTAMP() in Hive

Tags: hadoop, hive, hiveql

I am trying to run this function to get the Current Date in Hive but I am getting the following error:

> Error while compiling statement: FAILED: SemanticException No valid privileges Required privileges for this query: Server=server1->Db=_dummy_database->Table=_dummy_table->action=select;

I have searched online and being suggested following functions to get Current Date in Hive but all are giving same error:

```
SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()); --/Selecting Current Time stamp/

SELECT CURRENT_DATE; --/Selecting Current Date/

SELECT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP; --/Selecting Current Time stamp/
```

But all are showing error if I run them as they are given.

Comment: what error ..with which query..

Comment: SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp());  is working

Comment: Thanks Kishore. This works.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right Answers: 
1. SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp());  - Only works for Impala

2. SELECT from_unixtime(unix_timestamp()) from any_table_name; - Works in HIVE

NOTE: Must use FROM clause with any_table_name present in database for HIVE

Answer (score -1):

```
select unix_timestamp(current_timestamp) from table_name;
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. Code-only answers are discouraged.